# How to generate tables from data source using loop-back?

Tags: node.js, mean-stack, loopbackjs

I'm using **loop-back** in my project I'm having predefined data sources and I want to know how to convert these data sources into database tables using loop-back command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use migrations to create database schema from your datasource or vice versa. There is a post about migrations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29974947/migrating-built-in-models-to-databases/30038210#30038210).

CLI is used to auto-generate (scaffold) code and manage your application. You can find command-line reference [here](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/NODE/Command-line+reference). There is no command to do migration from CLI.

Comment: realy helpfull Thanks @A.Z