# How to store Oauth response in postgresql?

Tags: angularjs, postgresql, oauth, loopbackjs

I am using loopback framework(Node.js) with angular js(front end) and postgresql (DB)for my application,In my application i used third party login "passport-google-oauth".

After the google auth, call back url return the response as below mentioned code.

EX: http://localhost:3000/gauthServer

File: routes.js

```
app.get('/gauthServer', function(req, res) {
        console.log(req.cookies.currentUserEmail);
        console.log(req.cookies.currentUsername);
        console.log(req.cookies.currentUserId);
        console.log(req.cookies.accessToken);
        //res.redirect("/");
    });
```

In the above code it return the response correctly what i printed in console.log().

Expecting Result : I want the above results to store in postgresql DB.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple but too broad.

Basically what you have to do is:

1. Create datasource with [slc loopback:datasource command](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Connecting+models+to+data+sources) and select postgresql connector
2. Do npm i loopback-connector-postgresql --save
3. Use [slc loopback:model command](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Defining+models) to create model that will contain properties mentioned above and connect it to database. Again wizard will help you to do so.
4. Save your data to database using [create method](https://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback/#persistedmodel-create) on your model

You may also find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29974947/migrating-built-in-models-to-databases/30038210#30038210) useful.